# draw graph showing the variations in distance in an intensity of light

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I plot the function/graph below in the picture? My trial was not quite like what it should be
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
    \draw[thick, smooth,samples=100,domain=-5.5:5.5] plot(\x,{0.5+1.0/(2.0*(\x))*sin((3*(\x))*180/pi)});
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using general marmot logic, I would try something like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,declare function={
f(\x)=(1/(1+0.1*abs(\x)))*(cos((3*(\x))*180/pi)+1);}]
    \draw[thick, smooth,samples=101,domain=-5.5:5.5] 
    plot(\x,{3*f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

This choice emerged from the observations that your plot shows a symmetric function whose local minima are all at the same `y`-value.

Comment: If course, it is straightforward to add a grid, the axes and the other stuff, if needed.

Comment: \draw[->](-6.5,0)--(6.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-.8)--(0,7.5);
\foreach\x in {-6, -5, ..., 5,6}
\draw(\x, -.2)--(\x, .2);

When this is added, how can I change the function so that the minimum points fit the points on the x-axis?

Comment: @Thumbolt `declare function={f(\x)=(1/(1+0.1*abs(\x)))*(cos(\x*180)+1);}` or `declare function={f(\x)=(1/(1+0.1*abs(\x)))*(cos(\x*90)+1);}`.